# Add album artwork as subview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaitem

I am using the following code to add the now playing artwork as a subview in my application.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let artWork = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork)

    let image = artWork?.imageWithSize(CGSizeMake(300, 300))

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 300, 300)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Not only does the image not appear, I get this warning in the console:

```
moveCircleAround[2385:753430] BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted
```

Can someone with knowledge in Swift please help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to proceed in Xcode 7 beta. All interaction with MPMusicPlayerController is currently broken in iOS 9 beta. Use Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4 instead, until this is fixed.

**Edit** Fixed in beta 5, so it's safe to return to Xcode 7 now.

Comment: Hey Matt, do you have a source on this?

Comment: Why do you say interaction with MPMediaItems is broken? I am still able to access `musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.title` for example. Also, `artWork == nil = false`.

Comment: Well, _my_ app doesn't run at all and I get the BSXPCMessage thing. And others have complained of this on the forums. See for example https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9414.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully this gets fixed next beta.

Comment: As of iOS 9 beta 5, I'm not seeing issues like that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few cases where this code fails to get the artwork image:

- `musicPlayer` doesn't yet have a `nowPlayingItem`.
- The `nowPlayingItem` doesn't have an artwork or it's not downloaded yet.
- The artwork doesn't find an image of a matching size that you specified.

Try putting a breakpoint at the top of the function and step through the function and see which variable gets set to `nil`.

Also, note that the `BSXPCMessage` error could be a hint that the second issue above is the cause. Maybe try a different song and first check that it has an artwork in your Music app.

(Note that you can simplify the code by using `nowPlayingItem?.artwork` instead of `nowPlayingItem?.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork)`.)